# ActivityResult recreates, intent works during second launch attempt

Tags: android, fragment

I read the related topics thoroughly but have not managed to find a solution.
   I have a FragmentActivity that has several fragments in it. On the second fragment I am eager to launch an activity result on the editText touch.

```
edtStreetName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),GetAddressActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The Activity launches successfully. After some manipulation I want to get my result to the fragment.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // Do Activity menu item stuff here
                Log.e("menu pressed","menu!");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("name", "someStreetName");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
                return false;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;


    }
```

Now is the strange thing… The activity recreates itself and only after several recreations- the result is sent back to the fragment.. Sometimes it can take up to three or more tries.

```
Some log cat info:
03-26 00:25:23.634  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/launch ResultActivity﹕ launched
03-26 00:25:23.814  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/launch ResultActivity﹕ launched
03-26 00:25:23.894  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ created!
03-26 00:25:25.736  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/menu item﹕ is pressed!
03-26 00:25:25.856  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ created!
03-26 00:25:26.286  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ destroyed!
03-26 00:25:27.658  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/menu item﹕ is pressed!
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/INTENT Returned﹕ and name is  someStreetName
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/INTENT Returned﹕ and name is  someStreetName
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/frg﹕ onresumefrags
03-26 00:25:28.168  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ destroyed!
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

UPD 1
My Fragment's onActivityResult

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case (1):
                if (resultCode==-1)
                Log.e("INTENT Returned "," and name is  "+data.getStringExtra("name"));
        }
    }
```

Moar logs =-)
0

```
3-26 00:25:23.634  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/launch ResultActivity﹕ launched
03-26 00:25:23.814  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/launch ResultActivity﹕ launched
03-26 00:25:23.894  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ created!
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12229: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12235: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9800: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-26 00:25:23.924  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12232: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 396: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-26 00:25:23.964  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 359: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 361: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-26 00:25:23.974  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 00:25:24.034  32242-32246/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 10% free 9661K/10695K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 105ms
03-26 00:25:24.034  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
03-26 00:25:24.124  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-26 00:25:24.164  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
03-26 00:25:24.164  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4d839120, VC surface: 2, Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.164  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4d839120, 0x4d839120) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.374  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4fe149a8, 0x4fe149a8) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.374  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.374  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4fe149a8, android window 0x4fe08d40, Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.454  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:24.464  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:24.464  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:24.464  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:24.635  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4d839120, 0x4d839120) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:24.645  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:24.655  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:25.736  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/menu item﹕ is pressed!
03-26 00:25:25.856  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ created!
03-26 00:25:25.866  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-26 00:25:25.916  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
03-26 00:25:25.916  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4d8abaf8, VC surface: 3, Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:25.916  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4d8abaf8, 0x4d8abaf8) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:25.956  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4d839120, 0x4d839120) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:25.956  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:25.956  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4d839120, android window 0x50b407d8, Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:25.966  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:25.966  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-26 00:25:26.286  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/ResultActivity﹕ destroyed!
03-26 00:25:26.296  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4caa4968, 0x4caa4968) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:26.306  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:26.446  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot D/HAWAII_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x4fe14930, 0x4d8abaf8, 0x4d8abaf8) Thread: 32242
03-26 00:25:27.658  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/menu item﹕ is pressed!
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/INTENT Returned﹕ and name is  someStreetName
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/INTENT Returned﹕ and name is  someStreetName
03-26 00:25:27.778  32242-32242/com.tr.ctprot E/frg﹕ onresumefrags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I came across was to change EditText's TouchListener to a ClickListener
was:

```
edtStreetName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("launch ResultActivity","launched");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),GetAddressActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

became:

```
edtStreetName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),GetAddressActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });
```

Do not know why, but the Activity4Result stopped to recreate itself.